# GUI won't update till the end of function execution

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am working on simple Log In activity. I have a button and a rotation animation. When the button is clicked it should run the animation and then call the login method that takes a few seconds to finish.

The problem is that the animation starts when login function execution is finished (just before the layout is changed).

This is what i tried:

```
 private void BtnpPrijava_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() => {
            string username = edttxtKorisnicko.Text;
            string password = edttxtSifra.Text;

            var rotateAboutCornerAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Layout.RotationAnimation);
            imageViewForRotation.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            imageViewForRotation.StartAnimation(rotateAboutCornerAnimation);

            success = LogInController.Instance.Login(username, password);    

            if (success)
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            }
        }}
```

I also tried to put only these 3 lines of code in RunOnUIThread:

```
    var rotateAboutCornerAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Layout.RotationAnimation);
    imageViewForRotation.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    imageViewForRotation.StartAnimation(rotateAboutCornerAnimation);
```

Can anyone point me to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put all the code in the new thread and those 3 lines mentioned above in RunOnUiThread.

```
    private void BtnpPrijava_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            string korisnicko = edttxtKorisnicko.Text;
            string sifra = edttxtSifra.Text;

            if (korisnicko != "" && sifra != "")
            {
                bool prijavljen = false;


                var rotateAboutCornerAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Layout.RotationAnimation);

                this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    ivRotacija.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    ivRotacija.StartAnimation(rotateAboutCornerAnimation);
                });


                prijavljen = LogInController.Instance.Prijava(korisnicko, sifra);


                if (prijavljen)
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                }
                else
                {
                    ivRotacija.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
            }
        })).Start();
    }
```